# function accepts a command string but not Aliases

Tags: function, unix, alias

I created this doit function to execute system commands, scripts and aliases.

```
function doit {
doit_cmd=$*
if [[ $cmd_trace = "1" ]] then
    echo "+ $doit_cmd"
fi  

$doit_cmd 
ret=$?
return $ret
}
```

The doit function accepts a command string (including command parameters).
It first displays the given command and its parameters to stdout, then 
executes the command. I execute commands in scripts via the doit function 
to trace what commands are executed. The line "$doit_cmd" in the above doit 
function works beautifully for system commands and scripts, but failed when 
an alias is given to the doit function.

Here is a demonstration of the problem.

$ alias wi='whoami'
$ cmd_trace=1

$ doit whoami
+ whoami

root

$ doit wi
+ wi
doit[6]: wi:  not found

Can someone assist me on this problem? Is this a limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Execute your command using: `eval $doit_cmd`.

On a separate note, I think you should also change `$*` to `"$@"`.

Comment: Hi Dogbane, Thanks a ton for assistance and support. I have incorporated the changes and it is working fine.